# Superharmonic extension

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

We know the following classic result. If $K\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m>1$) is a compact set and $u$ is superharmonic on a neighborhood of $K$, then we can extend $u$ to a superharmonic function $\overline{u}$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$ that coincides with $u$ on $K$. For $|x|>$ some positive number $r$, we have $\overline{u}=a+b U(x)$, where $a$ is real, $b$ positive and $U(x)=-\log|x|$ if $m=2$ and $=|x|^{2-m}$ if $m>2$ ($|.|$ Euclidean norm) ( see "Classical Potential Theory", by Armitage and Gardiner, pg 192).

We notice that $\overline{u}$ is not superharmonic at $x=\infty$, but subharmonic. My question is: is there a way to take out one point $y_0$ from $K$, and then extend $u$ to a superharmonic function $\tilde{u}$ on $\mathbb{R}^m_\infty\setminus\{y_0\}$ such that on $K\setminus\{y_0\}$ $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ coincide? ($\mathbb{R}^m_\infty=\mathbb{R}^m\cup\{\infty\}$ one point compactification.)
By the way $u$ is superharmonic at infinity, if it is lower semicontinuous at infinity and $u(\infty)$ is bounded below by the average of $u$ over any  ball of sufficiently large radius (see Helms' "Introduction to Potential Yheory", chapter on the Dirichlet problem for unbounded regions).

Comment: It depends on what point $y_0$ you allow to use. If $y_0$ is an accumulation point of $K$ and $\lim_{y\to y_0}u(y)$ is finite then such extension is not possible. If $y_0$ is an isolated point of $K$ then it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, $y_0$ is an isolated point of $K$ indeed. But in this case how to construct the function?

Comment: In dimension 2, just send this $y_0$ to infinity, and use the known result. In other dimensions you may repeat the arguments from the proof of the result for $y_0=\infty$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. In dimension 2, by using the Kelvin transformation and sending $y_0$ to infinity, we obtain a subharmonic function outside $y_0$. But I don't see why the restriction of this function to $K$ is identical to $u$ (?)