# Superharmonic extension 3

Tags: real-analysis, brownian-motion, potential-theory

This question is related to the MO post
[Superharmonic extension 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384444/superharmonic-extension-2?noredirect=1&lq=1). Let $u$ be a superharmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^m$  ($m>2$) such that for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta$, $R>0$,
$$u(x)=\alpha+\beta |x|^{2-m}$$ for $|x|\geq R$. Given any  compact set $K$ in  $\mathbb{R}^m$  and any fixed point $y_0$ outside $K$,  Mateusz Kwaśnicki transfered the singularity of $u$ from $\infty$ to $y_0$ without changing the function on $K$; another words, he constructed a function $\overline{u}$ that is superharmonic on $\mathbb{R}^m\cup\{\infty\}$ outside $y_0$, and whose restriction to $K$ coincides with $u$.

My new question is: is it possible to do so, if $y_0$ is a given point in the interior of $K$, and not outside $K$, if we allow that $\overline{u}$ be unchanged on $K$ OUTSIDE a small neighborhood of $y_0$?
Notice that the same construction will not work here, because Mateusz Kwaśnicki uses the Green's function of $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus K$ with pole at $y_0$. So if $y_0$ is inside $K$, the Greens function will not be zero on $K$ anymore, and his $\overline{u}$ will not be equal to $u$ on $K$.

Comment: If you do not allow to change $u$ on $K$, what you you mean by changing it at $y_0$ which is interior point of $K$??

Comment: Thanks. I corrected!

Comment: Let $K'$ be equal to $K$ minus the small neighbourhood of $y_0$. If $y_0$ belongs to a bounded connected component of the complement of $K'$, then the answer is clearly negative. Just think that $u(x) = |x|^{2-m}$ and $K'$ is a spherical shell $B_R \setminus B_r$. Then how you modify $u$ on $B_r$ is completely irrelevant to the question what are the superharmonic extensions of $u$ to $B_R^c$.